# Coderaptor blank first page

Tags: pdf, html-to-pdf, princexml

I am using Docraptor (PrinceXML) to generate a PDF file from HTML.

I have a following problem.

The first page has a different footer as other than other pages, so I am using named pages. I can't use @page:first because in other documents I am creating the first page has a different header than this document

My HTML (for named (first) page):

```
<div class="container-regular">
    <div class="document_title">Document Title</div>
    <div class="footerfirst">
       Page Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@page footerfirst:first { 
    @bottom { 
      content: flow(footerfirst);
     }

     margin-bottom: 40mm;
}

#footer_first
{ 
   flow: static(footerfirst);
}

div.footer_first{
    page: footerfirst;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-before: avoid;
    prince-page-group: start;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

FOOTER:

```
<div id="footer_first">
     Footer text
</div>
```

This only happens if I use named page for first page, on all other pages the is no blank page.

Can somebody please help me with this and point me in the right direction?

Thanks and regards, Grega

Comment: This normally happens when there's HTML, even if it's invisible or empty before the first page occurs. The rendering engine has already created a page for that content, then it hits your named page and creates a second page, leaving the first page blank. The key is eliminating that extra HTML. Support@Docraptor.com should be able to help further too.

Comment: Thanks @jamespaden, you helped a lot. I did have some HTML before the named page. I changed my HTML to this and it works: `<div class="container-regular">
   <div class="footerfirst">
      <div class="document_title">Document Title</div>
      Page Content
    </div>`
</div>